# Sony Bravia (KDL-32EX402) audio connection fails

Tags: audio, connection, tv

Hey. I'm having trouble connecting my computers audio to the TV (Sony Bravia KDL-32EX402).

I'm using a standard AUX cable (some kind of adapter for L/R to go into the headphone plug on the computer). I'm connecting the other end to the back of the TV, it doesn't actually say "AUDIO IN" but it has to be (is also right below the "HDMI 1 AUDIO IN).

When changing to "PC-mode" and setting the audio input to "PC" nothing happens. (but the pictures get's transmitted fine by VGA).

I have checked that it's not the PC's headphone port, nor the AUX cable.

What to do, what to do ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual, the two RCA jacks below the “PC/HDMI1 AUDIO IN” jack are audio *outputs*, not inputs. There are stereo RCA audio inputs in the “COMPONENT IN” group (to the left of those outputs), but I'm not sure whether it is possible to use them together with the PC video input. If such switching is impossible, you will need to use a minijack-to-minijack cable plugged into the “PC/HDMI1 AUDIO IN” jack instead of your minijack-to-2xRCA cable.